# Change element class while dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change element class or any `css property` while dragging and it depends on elements position. So this is what i got so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/twfegqgc/

So it changes when element passes half of window but when it comes to end of window width it doesn't change and it should. So that is my problem.

HTML

```
<div id="sun" class="yellow"></div>
<div class="position"></div>
<div class="window"></div>
```

JS

```
var sun = $("#sun");

sun.draggable();

$("#sun").bind("drag", function(event, ui) {
    var halfWidth = $(window).width() / 2;
    var left = $(this).offset().left + 100;
    var windowWIdth = $(window).width() - 200;

    $('.position').html(left);
    $('.window').html(windowWIdth);

    if(left > halfWidth) {
        sun.removeClass('yellow');
        sun.addClass('red')
    } else if (left == windowWIdth) {
        sun.removeClass('red');
        sun.addClass('black')
    }

});
```

I am actually trying to create answer to some other question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the "if else" statement. After you are passing the mid-point you will always get into the first if statement. you should remove the "else" word and everything will work well

```
 if(left > halfWidth) {
    sun.removeClass('yellow');
    sun.addClass('red')
}


if (left == windowWIdth) {
        sun.removeClass('red');
        sun.addClass('black')
    }
```

here is a working example: [fixed solution](https://jsfiddle.net/twfegqgc/2/)

**Update**: 
In order it to work in all directions you should put another term in the if else statements:

```
if(left < halfWidth) {
    sun.addClass('yellow');
    sun.removeClass('red')
} else
if(left > halfWidth && left <= windowWIdth) {
    sun.removeClass('black')
    sun.removeClass('yellow');
    sun.addClass('red')
} else
if (left >= windowWIdth) {
    sun.removeClass('red');
    sun.addClass('black')
}
```

here is a working example: [updated solution](https://jsfiddle.net/twfegqgc/2/)

Comment: Thanks, is there way that colors change on dragging back?